# Can Angular dir-pagination paginate data dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have an Issue, i now how to use angular dir-paginate to paginate all the data, that comes from the service, but how can it be done if i want like, ten regists per page, and load them dynamically from page to page?

Answer (score 0):

[The answer for your question is here.](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#working-with-asynchronous-data)

Author wrote quite reasonable explanation how to work with the data in async mode.